# Divergence of a 2D vector field on a spherical Earth (Python/Basemap)

Tags: python, vector, matplotlib-basemap

I have 2D arrays of u (zonal) and v (meridional) components of the wind at several points, whose locations are given my corresponding 2D latitude and longitude arrays.

I would like to compute the divergence of this wind field. I understand that the divergence is just du/dx + du/dy, but because my x and y coordinates are latitude and longitude, it doesn't come out quite correctly. For example, a uniform meridonal wind everywhere on the globe (v = constant everywhere) would actually have divergence/convergence at the polls, even though the v array is just a constant number at every index.

I'd ultimately like to plot the divergence on a Basemap instance.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for divergence is depends on the coordinate system as you've  discovered. It's a worthwhile exercise to work out the formulas (use the change of coordinate formulas and the chain rule) but [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) has a helpful table of the necessary formulas.

You want the formula for spherical coordinates, and since you're working on the surface of the sphere, you'll want to hold *r*. This has the effect of dropping the first term and scaling the other two terms.

Comment: Would A_θ and A_φ be v and u, respectively? So dA_φ /dφ  would be something like diff(u)/diff(lon)?

Comment: A_θ and A_φ are, respectively, the components of your vector in the directions θ and φ (latitude and longitude, or zonal and meridional if you prefer.)

Comment: One other important thing to be aware of - those formulas are written with the assumption θ and φ will be measured in radians, not degrees.